Deploy update odoo on ubuntu not showing updates
I create a new module on odoo local environment once I deploy it on ubuntu server it's not reflect the change. am running odoo using service :
[Unit]
Description=Odoo
Requires=postgresql.service
After=network.target postgresql.service
[Service]
Type=simple
SyslogIdentifier=odoo
PermissionsStartOnly=true
User=odoo
Group=odoo
ExecStart=/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo-bin -c /opt/odoo/odoo/odoo.conf
StandardOutput=journal+console
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

can you please advice how we can reload and update odoo with new code ?
thank you
